# Put an offline link in Beamer presentation

Tags: urls, links, hyperlink

I have a html page save in my computer and I would like to know if its possible put the link for the html page in the Beamer presentation and when the click on the html page in the Beamer, This will redirect me to the html page without I need to access the internet. If it is possible, how can I do this?

Thanks in advance!

P.S.: I don't know if it is relevant, but the html page is a simulator. Will the simulator run even without the internet?

Comment: You can quickly test if the website runs without internet: open your browser, save the website, disconnect your internet connection and open the website.

Comment: for the link to a local file, see e.g. https://superuser.com/questions/247967/how-can-i-link-to-a-local-file-in-a-latex-document-typeset-with-pdflatex-on-mac

Comment: @samcarter, it works, thanks! Do you know if can I change the path file to a text? Because appears the path file rather than a text. I tried put "\url{file:///./path-to-file}{Text}", but it doesn't work.

Comment: Then you want `\href` and not `\url`